# To display huge number of data on Dojo tree

Tags: javascript, json, tree, dojo

I'm using Dojo Tree (dijit.tree) to display hierarchical data. Am using JSON to display the data in the tree. Each node in the tree will have more than 6 JSON attributes to describe the node. For eg. A node called country will have a JSON with attributes such as name, id, iconstyle, type, etc. And the tree gets displayed as below :
Root --> Country --> State --> City
Problem is when the data is huge. For eg, If there are more than 300 states and more than 1000 cities under a given country, the data is so huge that the browser crashes and it takes a lot of time to display. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: What kind of store are you using? `dojo/store/Memory`?

Comment: item file write store with forest tree model

Comment: Why don't you lazy load child nodes and download them when the node is opened?

Comment: When I search for a city or a building in that city, the tree should be highlighted on the searched city. That's my requirement. Others nodes I have implemented lazy loading only